# Drupal 6 alternative to Drupal 7's managed_file Field API type

Tags: 6, files

Is there a Drupal 6 alternative to the Drupal 7 managed_file field type?
I have an configuration form using multiple image fields, and I'm using managed_file field type in Drupal 7 which works perfectly and saves a bunch of work. This type doesn't seem to exist in 6, the fields just don't show up at all and theirs no mention of it in the 6 Field API reference, so I'm guessing it doesn't exist or exists in a different way?

Any alternatives/suggestions on how to implement this functionality in a Drupal 6 version would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: file upload example (http://drupal.org/project/examples) has a good example using `file` field type.

Comment: Helpful example but it doesn't support multiple files it seems like? and it doesn't show a file has already been attached when the page is reloaded either

Comment: @DanielWaters The Drupal 7 managed_file element doesn't support multiple uploads either, you'd need to roll that logic yourself

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear, by multiple uploads I don't mean per field I meant just more than one upload per page/form